# Convert Dropdownlist String Value to Date

Tags: string, vb.net, date, datetime, dropdown

I want to do a date comparison to check whether is the Before Period is bigger than After Periode
So far it has been working properly until the date range is a bit tricky

For example
The value is from a dropdownlist item
Before period is 21-10-2022
After period is 04-11-2022

It will trigger the error message I set if the before period is bigger than the period after

I have a code like this

```vb
If CDate(ddlPeriodeBefore.SelectedValue) <= CDate(ddlPeriodeBefore.SelectedValue) Then
   'Does the job if the the before period is smaller than after period
Else
   lblInfo.Text = "Period BEFORE Must Be SMALLER Than Period AFTER."
End If
```

Can anyone help me? it keeps saying **"conversion from string to date is not valid"**

I've tried datetime.parse, parse exact, cdate, convert.todatetime but nothing works so far, or maybe I used it the wrong way

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? How do you load the ddlitems, which format do you use?

Comment: Use `DateTime.Parse()` rather than `CDate()`. And don't call a date a "Period". A  period implies a _range_ with both a beginning and an end. So the full span you're trying to evaluate is a period, but each edge of the range is just a date. And don't call is "SMALLER". Instead, it must be "EARLIER".

Comment: @TimSchmelter i'm using databind to data table function, so I first load the data from database into data table and bind it into my dropdown and when i select the value it produce string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DateTime.Parse` works depends on your curren culture because you don't pass any. For me this works fine (but for you not):

```
Dim selectedValue1 = "21-10-2022"
Dim selectedValue2 = "04-11-2022"
Dim beforePeriod = Date.Parse(selectedValue1)
Dim afterPeriod = Date.Parse(selectedValue2)
```

So either you know the correct culture that you have used when you have created this string, then you can pass this as second parameter to `Date.Parse`, or you use `ParseExact`:

```
Dim beforePeriod = Date.ParseExact(selectedValue1, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim afterPeriod = Date.ParseExact(selectedValue2, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The culture is relevant because they can have different date separators and the order of the day-, month- and year-tokens are different.

Comment: when i try date.parse it gives me error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." the value of my dropdown is just 21-10-2022 and my after is also just 04-11-2022, i seriously don't know why it doesn't works

Comment: I have told you why it doesnt work. If your current culture uses a different order for day and month, so first month and then day, the first date will not parse. Or if it uses not minutes as date separator. You have multiple options to fix that, my answer suggests two and shows one(ParseExact).

Comment: Turns out there is a bit of a problem in how i fetch the data from my database i convert that into varchar instead of date, but using your method of date.parse does works thanks

Comment: @Lydia: Yes, then the real bug was that you convert it to `varchar` instead of keeping the `datetime`-type. Then you can read it as `DateTime` in .NET and you don't need to parse it and you avoid format issues.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Schmelter's suggestion is not wrong, but I did want to provide an alternative. Create a collection of Tuple, add the dates (both formatted string and native value) to the collection, then bind the control to the list.

Here is the alternative:

```vb
Dim dates As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, DateTime))()
Dim today = DateTime.Today
For daysSubtract = 90 To 0 Step -1
    Dim dateToAdd = today.AddDays(-daysSubtract)
    dates.Add(New Tuple(Of String, DateTime)(dateToAdd.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), dateToAdd))
Next

ddlPeriodeBefore.ValueMember = "Item1"
ddlPeriodeBefore.DisplayMember = "Item2"
ddlPeriodeBefore.DataSource = dates

ddlPeriodeAfter.ValueMember = "Item1"
ddlPeriodeAfter.DisplayMember = "Item2"
ddlPeriodeAfter.DataSource = dates
```

Now when you go to get the selected value, you can use a simpler conversion since the stored object is already a DateTime:

```vb
Dim beforePeriod = DirectCast(ddlPeriodeBefore.SelectedValue, DateTime)
Dim afterPeriod = DirectCast(ddlPeriodeAfter.SelectedValue, DateTime)

If (beforePeriod <= afterPeriod) Then
    ' ...
Else
    lblInfo.Text = "Period BEFORE Must Be SMALLER Than Period AFTER."
End If
```

The advantage to this approach is that you do not have to refactor your code if the date formatting changes.